# Best way to debug git-hooks

Tags: githooks

What is the best way to debug git-hooks?

The way I prefer is adding statements to add output to a log file. For example, the following.

```
echo 'post-receive executed' >> hooks.log
```

Is there a better approach or way to do logging?

Answer (score 27):

#### Debugging the hook as a shell script

I doubt that it is the script itself which needs to be looked at, however if that turns out to be the case, then the next step is to do what you normally would to debug shell scripts (since that is what the default commit-msg hook is).

I would start by changing the she-bang line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh -xv` and then revel in the uber-verbose output as the script is executed when you do a `git commit --amend`

Comment: This is not a good answer. It does nothing to explain how and when `git commit --amend` should be used, only that it needs to be used.

Comment: `git commit --amend` re-commits the current commit, causing all hooks to run. To anyone who's at the level of git knowledge to be writing and debugging hooks, this is pretty clear. I'm opening to editing the answer to add a (short!) explanation, but the answer is still very good as is.