# VS Code - Debug Pre-push Git Hook?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Have a git hook I'm wondering how I can set up to debug/step through in VS Code.

What I'm trying to figure out is whether or not I can step through code in my pre-push hook in my project under `.git/hooks/prepush`, as I can't just set breakpoints in the file.

Would it be simpler to just make it a `.sh` extension and step through that way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to debug git-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291854/best-way-to-debug-git-hooks)

Comment: @alex will check that out, thank you