# How to log requests in/out of `exec`

Tags: git, gitlab, sh, exec, gitlab-omnibus

I've got this git pre-receive hook on my GitLab-CE server:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is the single source of truth for where Gitaly's embedded Git hooks are.
exec "$GITALY_BIN_DIR/gitaly-hooks" "$(basename $0)" "$@"
```

I have a keen interest in what's passing through this exec command, because it's "not working".

How can I capture the input and output to the `exec` command and log it to a file or files?  Thank you!

This intends to tee the output, but has a `syntax error: redirection unexpected`.  I also want to log the input.

```
exec "$GITALY_BIN_DIR/gitaly-hooks" "$(basename $0)" "$@"  &> >(tee -a /var/log/git-as-svn/pre-receive.2.3.log)
```

Comment: Please replace the _bash_ tag by a _shell_ tag, since this is not a bash script.

Comment: For seeing the input parameters, you could simply dump "$@" to some logfile before doing the exec. I don't know gitaly, but why are you doing an `exec` here? Is it the supposed way to define a hook in Gitaly?

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html especially [Custom error messages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#custom-error-messages)

See also [Best way to debug git-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291854/best-way-to-debug-git-hooks)

You could change the first line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh -x`.

Or you could write the value of $@ to a file as user1934428 suggested.

---

I am sorry, I didn't read the question closely enough. How about using `strace`, then you can see what was the input and the output?

For example:

```
$ cat test.sh                                                                                                                          #!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/strace -f -o /tmp/strace.out -s 9999 /bin/bash -c "exec ./hello.sh"
$ cat hello.sh                                                                                                                         #!/bin/sh
echo What is your name?
read name
echo hello $name
$ ./test.sh                                                                                                                            What is your name?
John
hello John
$ grep read\(0 /tmp/strace.out                                                                                                         
104   read(0, "J", 1)                   = 1
104   read(0, "o", 1)                   = 1
104   read(0, "h", 1)                   = 1
104   read(0, "n", 1)                   = 1
104   read(0, "\n", 1)                  = 1
$ grep write\( /tmp/strace.out                                                                                                         
104   write(1, "What is your name?\n", 19) = 19
104   write(1, "hello John\n", 11)      = 11
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it doesn't answer the question.  -x and $@ reveal the binary being called, but do not show the input and output of that command.  I believe `exec` switches the io streams.